# Sets of arrays of different variable length (Julia)

Tags: julia

E.g., when processing the set of plane contours: 
each one consists of N nodes and may be described by the matrix N*2 
(x, y coordinates of every node). 
The number of nodes in the contour is changed during processing.
What is the simplest recommended object (data type) in Julia for such set of contours?

Comment: Are they evenly sampled?  Don't mutate them and just use ranges!

Comment: No, they are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest possible in what way? See GeometryTypes.jl. The "simplest" object, by some definitions of simple, is a vector of 3D points, with (x, y) the node coordinates and z the contour height value. You could use Point3f0 with Float32 or Point3d{T} for Int or Float64. Here you could index with ranges, as Matt suggested above.

If there is a desire for "simple" here to mean keep the contour value in a different category altogether than the (x, y) points, perhaps to save memory, then a Dict{Float32, Vector{Point2f0}}() would do that. The Dict keys would represent the contour numbers. This allows quick indexing by contour but terrible indexing by X and Y ranges as a price for the better memory usage.

If the contour indexes are so regular and predefined that storing them with the points does not matter, you could use Vector{Vector{Point2f0}}, a vector of vectors of Point2f0, with one vector of Point2f0 per contour in your vector of vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bill, for the valuable information.